# Free MariaDB forward engineering tool

Tags: gratis, linux, mariadb

At this point, MariaDB 10.3 and MySQL 8.0.xx are now different enough that the most recent version of MySQL Workbench has difficulties working with MariaDB.  Given this problem is likely to get worse, I have attempted to look for an alternative client for MariaDB.  However, I have been unsuccessful in finding one with the desired features, which are as follows:

- Free/open source (free is more important)
- Capable of forward engineering an ERD to a database
- Contains SQL query client
- Version for Linux (and Windows if possible)

I know that alternatives for MySQL workbench is already a question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/390324/alternative-to-mysql-workbench); however, I am specifically looking for client that can perform forward engineering.

**Edit 1**

From a comment on the previous website, I thought I would add a little clarification.  The ability to forward engineer an ERD into a database is an uncommon feature in free software that is not present (to the best of my knowledge) in any of the alternatives listed in the link above.